# Angular Pipe Space

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript, angular6

I am using pipe to apply what kind of currency it will be displayed. R$ or $. But it gets stuck with Total value, I wanted to know how I get a spacing between pipe values
[image]

> Expected result
>   R$ 86.20

```js
<ng-container matColumnDef="totalValue">
            <mat-header-cell class="mr-16" *matHeaderCellDef fxFlex="15"  fxLayoutAlign="end center">Total R$</mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell  class="mr-16" *matCellDef="let element" fxFlex="15"  fxLayoutAlign="end center" >
              <p class="text-truncate" matTooltip='{{ element.totalValue  | currency : element.currency : "symbol" }}'>
                {{ element.total | currency : element.currency : "symbol" }}
              </p>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>
```

Comment: You have to edit the pipe execution function which has to be somewhere in your code (currencypipe.ts) and add the space in it

Comment: I have some component that uses this same module, changing it can affect.

Comment: So add a boolean value to the function spacing:true and handle it

Comment: Is this a method that I have to edit? Sorry, I did not get the logic to change. Was this method that would change? transform(value: any, currencyCode?: string, display?: 'code' | 'symbol' | 'symbol-narrow' | string | boolean, digitsInfo?: string, locale?: string): string | null;

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom `CurrencySpacePipe`, which extends `CurrencyPipe` and inserts a space after the currency symbol:

```
import { Pipe } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe } from '@angular/common';

@Pipe({ name: "currencySpace" })
export class CurrencySpacePipe extends CurrencyPipe {
  transform(value: number, ...args: any[]): string {
    return super.transform(value, ...args).replace(/([^\d.,])(\d)/, "$1 $2");
  }
}
```

and use that pipe, instead of the standard `CurrencyPipe`, in your markup:

```
{{ element.total | currencySpace : element.currency : "symbol" }}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-translate-uoej7f) for a demo.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the space at the end as shown in the code below. It works`s for me. I am using Angular 6 by the way.

```
<span>{{ product.price | currency:'USD' + ' ' }}</span>
```